# Windows : Only Run Install Startup Script if Directory Doesn't Exist

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, startup-scripts

I want to install some programs via a startup script, but once it has run for the first time it'll just reinstall wasting time and overwriting. It's a Server 2008 R2.

Somewhere I found this

```
IF NOT "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client"=="" 
(
    echo "Already Installed"
) 
else 
(
    "\\192.168.1.104\Programs\Microsoft Security Essentials\Microsoft Security Essentials.exe" /s /runwgacheck
)

IF NOT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0"=="" 
(
    echo "Already Installed"
) 
else 
(
    "\\192.168.1.104\Programs\Adobe Reader\AdbeRdr1012_en_US.exe" /sAll /rs /msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES
)
```

But it doesn't work. How could I get it to?

Comment: What scripting language is this supposed to be? It doesn't appear to be valid Windows .BAT file syntax, or VBscript, or Jscript, or PowerShell.

Comment: It's a batch file, but it doesn't work so to be honest I'm happy to use anything.

Comment: Yes, you need to use "IF NOT EXIST" in batch files to test for file or direcotory existence, and get rid of the =="" part. I just voted Josh's answer below up. I didn't even recognize it was a batch file because of that, I thought it was Kixtart or some other obscure scripting tool. (Of course .BAT is a "weird" language too, but it is not obscure ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You need `IF EXIST` instead of just `IF` for batch programming.

*e.g.*

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client" (
  :: Install product
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're running AD, why don't you try distributing these products via MSI and GPO?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only person who thinks this every time I read yet another post about how to install stuff with a GPO-based startup script.

Comment: Because these programs don't have an MSI Installer. I've done it with Chrome and Handbrake, but it's not possible to do it for these.

Comment: Adobe Reader X most assuredly does have an MSI. ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.0.0/en_US/

Comment: Also, 'mseinstall.exe -x' will extract the MSI installers for MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Have your script drop a flag, create a text file or something, when the install completes that your script will look for on the subsequent runs.  If it finds the flag it ends the process and doesn't re-install.  If the flag doesn't exist it completes the install.

Comment: That does not cover the case of the product already being manually installed.

Comment: Correct.  But if I read his question he says he wants to install something, then once it has run not have it run again the next time the startup script runs.  If he wants to check for something that may already be installed prior to this he's going to have to add more checks to his process.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly my point.

Comment: Sorry but how would I do that exactly? (And that way would work perfectly)

Comment: Ed - he's saying that when one of your installer BAT files successfully installs a product (CHECK FOR RETURN CODES!), you can have it leave a file on the machine that indicates success. Next time the BAT runs, if it sees that file there, it would just exit (or continue) at that point. But if you can get the syntax for checking for a file, you should also be able to get the syntax for checking for a folder, which is what you were first asking for. Spend some time boning up on your BAT file skills.

Comment: Have your script check for a file that's part of the installation and if the file doesn't exist proceed with the install.  That would get you around having to drop a flag file.

Comment: But what would I type into the .BAT file to do that?

Comment: Look at this Ed: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-if-exist-else/15828.html  That's a basic outline of what you want to do.

Comment: What's wrong with this syntax because it gives an error?  `if exist C:/Installations/MicrosoftSecurityEssentials.txt
(
 echo Already Installed
) 
else 
(
 "\\192.168.1.104\Programs\Microsoft Security Essentials\Microsoft Security Essentials.exe" /s /runwgacheck
 @CON >> "C:/Installations/MicrosoftSecurityEssentials.txt"
)`

Comment: Ed, this is not the best place to ask people to line-by-line troubleshoot your scripts. Start simple - write a BAT with a single action and see if that works as expected. Change one thing at a time. Go from there.

Comment: FWIW, that script does not give me a syntax error - it works for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you're doing with @CON ...

Answer (score 0):

To test if a directory exists test for the presence of the "nul" file.
This will work in BAT and CMD scripts on ANY Windows version.

Just testing for the folder itself often fails, especially if the folder is on a network-drive or accessed by UNC path.

Like this:

```
if exists c:\somedir\nul (
  echo folder somedir exists in c:\
)
```

You can also use the trick to see if a drive-letter is in use or not.
E.g  if exists z:\nul will return true if z: is mapped on a network drive or if it is a DVD-drive, even if there is no disk in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2015, check out some PowerShell.

> if (!(Test-Path -Path "$Env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft Security Client" ))
>   {
>
> ```
> Write-Host "Not Installed, Installing..."
> iex "\\192.168.1.104\Programs\Microsoft Security Essentials\Microsoft Security Essentials.exe /s /runwgacheck"
> ```
>
> }
>
> if (!(Test-Path -Path "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Adobe\Reader 10.0" ))
>   {
>
> ```
> Write-Host "Not Installed, Installing..."
> iex "\\192.168.1.104\Programs\Adobe Reader\AdbeRdr1012_en_US.exe /sAll /rs /msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES"
> ```
>
> }